# POS tagging a single word in spaCy

Tags: nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

spaCy POS tagger is usally used on entire sentences. Is there a way to efficiently apply a unigram POS tagging to a single word (or a list of single words)?

Something like this:

```
words = ["apple", "eat", good"]
tags = get_tags(words) 
print(tags)
> ["NNP", "VB", "JJ"]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any result coming from a solution to this, will be inaccurate. The reason spaCy expects sentences, is because you usually need context to decide on the POS tag...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English unigrams are often hard to tag well, so think about why you want to do this and what you expect the output to be. (Why is the POS of `apple` in your example `NNP`? What's the POS of `can`?)

spacy isn't really intended for this kind of task, but if you want to use spacy, one efficient way to do it is:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

# disable everything except the tagger
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "tagger"]
nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes)

# use nlp.pipe() instead of nlp() to process multiple texts more efficiently
for doc in nlp.pipe(words):
    if len(doc) > 0:
        print(doc[0].text, doc[0].tag_)
```

See the documentation for `nlp.pipe()`: https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe

Comment: Your argument is exactly on point. Mind you sometimes there is no sufficient corpus available in certain languages and POS tagging all the words can be desirable.

Comment: I also want to say thanks for Your excellent help, I was looking for this answer for quite a while but didn't manage to come across this question.

Comment: Unfortunately spacy fails to perform on single words. For example in German it categorizes everything as noun: (tested: Auto, Autos, brachte, bringen, fuhr, klein, kleiner, schön, werden), despite German having a clear distinction of writing every noun as capitalized.

Comment: This is an older answer for v2. In v3, you need to include both `tok2vec` and `tagger` in the trained pipelines for the tagger to work.

Comment: Thank you, @aab. It works now kinda... instead of NOUN, VERB, etc I can see NNP, NNS, VBD tags. I guess "final" POS only is generated with the full pipe. 

As for the tags, they can be mapped in this case, using this docs:
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/glossary.py

Comment: If you want `token.pos` instead of `token.tag` that's a slightly different question. For v3 `en_core_web_*` models, you need `tok2vec`, `tagger`, and `attribute_ruler` to get POS. See: https://spacy.io/models#design

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

word_list = ["apple", "eat", "good"]
for word in word_list:
   doc = nlp(word)
   print(doc[0].text, doc[0].pos_)
```

alternatively, you can do

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = spacy.tokens.doc.Doc(nlp.vocab, words=word_list)

for name, proc in nlp.pipeline:
    doc = proc(doc)

pos_tags = [x.pos_ for x in doc]
```

Comment: This works, but isn't the fastest way to do this with spacy.

Comment: Your second suggestion tags the words as if they were in a single sentence like "apple eat good", which isn't going to give the same results as tagging the words individually.